# Retrieve globalpicklist/globalvalueset without SOQL

Tags: apex, query, picklist, schema, global-picklist

Is it possible to retrieve the values of a Global Picklist/GlobalValueSet using Schema class without a SOQL ?

Comment: Can't you just use describes on a field that implements it?

Comment: @AdrianLarson - what if a field does use it? for example a `Global Value Set` which is used with `Custom Settings` which does not support `picklist`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My strategy here would simply be to describe a picklist field that implements the `Global Picklist`.

```
SObjectField picklistUsingGlobal = SObjectType.MyObject__c.fields.PicklistUsingGlobal__c.getSObjectField();
List<PicklistEntry> entries = picklistUsingGlobal.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
```

Comment: I get `Compile failure on line 1, column 14: Illegal assignment from Schema.DescribeFieldResult to Schema.SObjectField` using this snippet on `Contact.Custom_Field_With_Value_Set__c`. Using Hari's snippet all works fine.

Answer (score 18):

```
Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = <Object_API_Name>.<Field_API_Name>.getDescribe();
Schema.sObjectField T = F.getSObjectField();
List<PicklistEntry> entries = T.getDescribe().getPicklistValues();
```

Comment: But how can you tell if a field is employing a global value set?  Where can you access that dependency information?  For example, I want to loop around all the fields in my object and preform a task only if that field uses a particular global value set.  Use of that GVS groups these fields together by purpose.  To pick a field that is 'known' to be using a GVS requires information that should not be necessary.